# How combine results from multiple models in Google Vertex AI?

Tags: google-ai-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have multiple models in Google Vertex AI and I want to create an endpoint to serve my predictions.
I need to run aggregation algorithms, like the Voting algorithm on the output of my models.
I have not found any ways of using the models together so that I can run the voting algorithms on the results.
Do I have to create a new model, curl my existing models and then run my algorithms on the results?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community: My question is about infrastructure, and whether there is functionality in Google Vertex AI to generally solve a very common goal (picking the result of one out of multiple models). I do not seek code examples, and I believe my question is agnostic to programming languages and frameworks.
There might be information missing from my question, but it is not code.

Comment: Hello. If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built provision to implement aggregation algorithms in Vertex AI. To `curl` results from the models then aggregate them, we would need to deploy all of them to individual endpoints. Instead, I would suggest the below method to deploy the models and the meta-model(aggregate model) to a single endpoint using [custom containers for prediction](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/use-custom-container). The custom container requirements can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements).

You can load the model artifacts from GCS into a custom container. If the same set of models are used (i.e) the input models to the meta-model do not change, you can package them inside the container to reduce load time. Then, a custom HTTP logic can be used to return the aggregation output like so. This is a sample custom flask server logic.

```py
def get_models_from_gcs():
    ## Pull the required model artifacts from GCS and load them here.
    models = [model_1, model_2, model_3]
    return models

def aggregate_predictions(predictions):
    ## Your aggregation algorithm here
    return aggregated_result


@app.post(os.environ['AIP_PREDICT_ROUTE'])
async def predict(request: Request):
    body = await request.json()
    instances = body["instances"]
    inputs = np.asarray(instances)
    preprocessed_inputs = _preprocessor.preprocess(inputs)

    models = get_models_from_gcs()
    predictions = []
    
    for model in models:
        predictions.append(model.predict(preprocessed_inputs))

    aggregated_result = aggregate_predictions(predictions)

    return {"aggregated_predictions": aggregated_result}
```